# Make Image overflow the hero element and align to the bottom-right

Tags: html, css

**My Code**: https://jsfiddle.net/jqno1x6p/

I have this code, at the top, I have a hero element where I would like to place an image at the bottom-right section of the hero element and then overflow into the next section. I am not sure how to accomplish this.

Here is how my Hero element is set up:

```
<div class="hero-image">
      <img src="https://www.communityled.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/community-hero.png" alt="bg-hero" />
      <div class="hero-text">
        <h1>Tennant management, <span class="emphasize">innovated.</span></h1>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean by overflow into the next section... you can set the `overflow:hidden` on `hero-image` class, to hide the overflown portion of the image:

```css
.hero-image {
  overflow:hidden; // <-- hide the overflow
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <nav class="navbar">
      <span class="brand"><a href="index.php">tensys</a></span>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="nav-link left"><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link left"><a href="">Our Story</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link right"><a href="">Services</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link right"><a href="">Client Portal</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="hero-image">
      <img src="https://www.communityled.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/community-hero.png" alt="bg-hero" />
      <div class="hero-text">
        <h1>Tennant management, <span class="emphasize">innovated.</span></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

A different approach (and perhaps better one) would be to fit the image to your page, by setting the image width equal to your page width - the height would be adjusted:

```css
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <nav class="navbar">
      <span class="brand"><a href="index.php">tensys</a></span>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="nav-link left"><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link left"><a href="">Our Story</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link right"><a href="">Services</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link right"><a href="">Client Portal</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="hero-image" style="overflow:hidden">
      <img src="https://www.communityled.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/community-hero.png" alt="bg-hero" />
      <div class="hero-text">
        <h1>Tennant management, <span class="emphasize">innovated.</span></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```